# Why projective varieties are non affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory, projective-space

Why the complex projective space $P^n$ and its irreducible Zariski closed subsets are examples of non-affine varieties?

I read this on Siddarth Kannan - An informal introduction to blow-ups, page 1.

Comment: Informally, the answer below says that if $X$ is affine, there are non-constant algebraic functions defined on all of it (arising from restrictions of polynomial functions on an ambient vector space). On the other hand, on a projective variety $X$, the only algebraic functions defined on all of $X$ are the constants. If you work over the complex numbers, this follows from the fact that a holomorphic function on a compact complex manifold is constant, because it is holomorphic and bounded.

Comment: @DamianRössler your comment was very helpful to me, could you explain a bit more the part "on a projective variety X, the only algebraic functions defined on all of X are the constants"? Or suggest a reference/theorem to understand this. I understood it in the context of complex numbers. Thanks.

Comment: You could have a look at III.5 in https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/Miles.Reid/MA4A5/UAG.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X$ is an affine variety, $X = {\rm Spec} A$, then $A$ is the ring of global sections of the structure sheaf ${\mathcal O}_X$. But for a projective variety $X$, any global section of ${\mathcal O}_X$ is a constant function. The ring of global sections is just the ground field, and its spectrum is a point, not $X$.

Comment: Could you suggest a book to understand the concepts you mentioned in your answer? For example "global section" and "structure sheaf". I am new in algebraic geometry. Is Hartshorne a good reference for this concepts?